# Make all gvim windows share a single R process and screen session

Tags: r, vim

Old versions of the vim-r-plugin offered an option for choosing whether all vim/gvim instances used their own R processes (and screen sessions) or a single shared process (using the `vimrplugin_single_r` variable). [See section 5.2 of the documentation of version 101217](http://binfalse.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/vim-r-plugin-101217.html).

The current version of the plugin use separate R processes by default and despite my best efforts I am at a loss on how to change it back to a single process. Does anybody know how?

**Edit**

The best solution I have found is to use version 0.9.9.1, which was the last version including this option.

Comment: Have you asked the plugin's author; he should know best?!

Comment: True. I reported it as [an issue in the vim-r-plugin's github project](https://github.com/jcfaria/Vim-R-plugin/issues/38) since I couldn't figure out a more suitable way. I hope they respond even though it is a mere user question and not a development question.